# LobbySystem not working? Minecraft Plugin

Tags: plugins, minecraft

I have a problem:
I wrote a lobby plugin for a Minecraft server and now it doesn't quite work anymore.
In what way:
As soon as I reinstall the plugin, everything works perfectly. But as soon as I change something in a config file, only one method of the plugin loads.
I have linked the plugin here:
[Plugin](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13lU5TdwWy2iyC-lISkgms0jszkBtAUFY/view?usp=sharing)
[Source Code](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1t68LLfGCpEh5JeXz5sZOx2RnJJLsHqv1?usp=sharing)

Would be cool if you guys can help me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appear because of lines like this one:

```java
new File("plugins//Lobysystem//preandsuffixes.yml");
```

#### 1) Don't write your own folder

Spigot already has API to do it. In the `onEnable` method, you can do `saveDefaultConfig()` that will create the folder for the plugin's config.

#### 2) Use Spigot's informations

Such as spigot have multiple way to make config file fastly, you can do something like this (already with the plugin instance):

```java
new File(getDataFolder(), "preandsuffixes.yml");
```

#### 3) The static method will no longer work

Yes, if you have to use the plugin instance, all of the `static {}` method will not work. If you really want to keep a static method to load everything, you can do something like that:

```java
public static loadConfig(Main plugin) {
   myconfig = new File(plugin.getDataFolder(), "preandsuffixes.yml");
}

@Override
public void onEnable() {
   loadConfig(this);
}
```

#### 4) Stackoverflow guidelines

It's off-topic for an answer, but few tips :

- Try to don't include link to download unknow source
- Add a minimal reproductible example instead of just giving all the code
- Don't decompile plugin.
- Take the time to identify problem and to be more clear than "it was working but now it's no longer working"